# How to construct an instance of the SqlDecimal datatype that specifies precision and scale

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46taf6xh.aspx) has documentation about how to construct a new instance of the SqlDecimal data type that includes specifying precision and scale, which can only be set at construction time.

Here's an example that works, but I don't understand how to set the value property:

```
SqlDecimal Test2 = new SqlDecimal(10, 3, false, new int[4] { 2, 1, 0, 0 });
```

When I print the following debug statements, I see that the Precision and Scale parameters are straight forward, but I don't understand how the value is determined from the integer array of length 4.

```
? Test.Precision
10
? Test.Scale
3
? Test2.Value
-4294967.298
```

How are the 4 integers "combined" to specify the value? There's no example and no explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int[4] { 2, 1, 0, 0 }
=
96-127: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000   -- 0
64- 95: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000   -- 0
32- 63: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001   -- 1
00- 31: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010   -- 2
```

The value of this 128-bit binary is

```
2 ^ 32 + 2 ^ 1 = 4294967298
```

Because the scale is 3, the decimal place is moved 3 to the left, making it 4294967.298
And the third parameter to SqlDecimal constructure being `false` makes it a negative value.

Comment: I see that the value of the first array position, p1, is treated as a decimal number, p1 ^ 1 (or 2 ^ 0.) This value is summed with p2 * (2 ^ 32). Would value of the next position be p3 * (2^64) and then p4 * (2^ 128)?

Comment: I don't think you get to use p4. It should come up with an error because even though SqlDecimal is loosely modelled on .net *decimal* type (102/128-bits), the actual precision of a SqlDecimal type maxes out at 38 or so.