# How to use SqlDecimal Constructor (Byte, Byte, Boolean, Int32[])

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-types

I can't find many resources regarding the use of the overloads of the SqlDecimal constructor.

```
decimal d = 2539075.3809m;
SqlDecimal.ConvertToPrecScale(d, 20, 4); //works
new SqlDecimal(20, 4, d >= 0, decimal.GetBits(d)); //throws Arithmetic Overflow
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136336/how-to-construct-an-instance-of-the-sqldecimal-datatype-that-specifies-precision

Comment: Reading the description of `GetBits` and the `bits` parameter to the constructor shows that they are quite different beasts. (`bits` is described as a 128-bit integer - `GetBits` says "The first, second, and third elements of the returned array contain the low, middle, and high 32 bits of the 96-bit integer number." and then describes an encoding scheme for the final 32 bits)